# Internet citation using APA

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I'm looking for a way to include Internet citations in my bibliography and 'print' them using APA style. Currently I have `natbib` and `apa-good.bst`, but from what I've been able to gleam from Google, there is no support in `natbib` for online citations. There were mentions of BibLaTex, but since I'm new to TeX I have no idea how to use that.

Is there a way to get Internet citations correctly in TeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> ... there is no support in `natbib` for online citations.

Sadly (or, rather, fortunately!), this claim is *incorrect*. Moreover, the `apa-good.bst` bibliography style file recognizes a field named `url` among the valid field names. Here's the file's bibtex code for the function `write.url`:

```
FUNCTION {write.url}
{ url empty$
    { skip$ }
    { "\newline\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * write$ newline$ }
  if$ 
}
```

You'll need to have the `url` package loaded (to make it understand the instructions `\url` and `\urlprefix`).

If you don't like the `\newline` instruction, which tells LaTeX to insert a line break before the start of the URL, you can remove it from the code; just save the file to something like "myapa-good.bst", and then invoke this new file. However, the linebreak may be part of APA style and hence shouldn't be eliminated willy-nilly.

To sum up, using any of `natbib`'s citation commands, you should get bibliography entries with associated URLs (assuming, of course, that the entries' URL fields aren't blank!)