# Citing websites in APA style with Zotero

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, zotero

Using `natbib` and `apa-good` as style, I am having problems displaying a citation of type website or blog post.

```
\usepackage{natbib}    
\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{msc_thesis}

Test \citep{schroeder_facebook_2012}
```

`msc_thesis.bib` contains, when taking the metadata directly from a website using Zotero:

```
@misc{schroeder_facebook_2012,
    title = {Facebook Hits One Billion Active Users},
    url = {http://mashable.com/2012/10/04/facebook-one-billion/},
    abstract = {Facebook just officially reached one billion active users, Facebook {CEO} and co-founder Mark Zuckerberg has announced.},
    urldate = {2013-07-17},
    journal = {Mashable},
    author = {Schroeder, Stan},
    month = oct,
    year = {2012},
}
```

APA style should be, according to http://www.studygs.net/citation.htm:

**Author. (Date published if available; n.d.--no date-- if not). Title of article. Title of web site . Retrieved date. From URL.**

But what I get is:

Schroeder, S. (2012). Facebook hits one billion active users.

I don't know whether `apa-good` is a "good" choice, it has always worked well for other type of media.

Comment: the answer to [Internet citation using APA](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36571) helps to figure out why the `url` doesn't appear at all. As to the formatting you're after, `apa-good` might not be a good choice... (BTW, you should add a link to it, since it's not available on CTAN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A `biblatex` solution

As I mentioned in the comments, [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36589) to [Internet citation using APA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36571) points out that `apa-good.bst` requires the [`url`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/url). But since the `apa-good.bst` style I found didn't produce the output you're expecting, I'd suggest [**`biblatex`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex), which has an APA style (called [`biblatex-apa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{schroeder_facebook_2012,
  title = {Facebook Hits One Billion Active Users},
  url = {http://mashable.com/2012/10/04/facebook-one-billion/},
  abstract = {Facebook just officially reached one billion active users, Facebook {CEO} and co-founder Mark Zuckerberg has announced.},
  urldate = {2013-07-17},
  journal = {Mashable},
  author = {Schroeder, Stan},
  month = oct,
  year = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{schroeder_facebook_2012}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex-apa example]

Although the output is the same, a more adequate entry type in biblatex would be `@online` (notice also the `date` field):

```
@online{schroeder2012,
  title = {Facebook Hits One Billion Active Users},
  url = {http://mashable.com/2012/10/04/facebook-one-billion/},
  abstract = {Facebook just officially reached one billion active users, Facebook {CEO} and co-founder Mark Zuckerberg has announced.},
  urldate = {2013-07-17},
  journal = {Mashable},
  author = {Schroeder, Stan},
  date = {2012-10},
}
```

**N.B.** According to [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-apa) (§1, "Important Changes"), `biblatex-apa` relies on the usage of `biber` instead of `bibtex` as the backend (It's the default behavior of biblatex, but I added the corresponding option to the MWE to make it clear).

About moving to `biblatex`, I'd suggest the following questions:

- [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)
- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)
- [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)
- [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)

Comment: Well... I understand that `biblatex` might be the right solution.. but I can't get it to run correctly in my TeXnicCenter.

Comment: That's because `biblatex-apa` requires `biber` instead of `bibtex` as the backend. You'd probably need to configure TeXnicCenter to run it, as suggested in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16577/5872)

Comment: I know about `biber` - and it finally worked (was a compat problem between `biblatex` and the former). Thanks for your advice, I'll accept.